# '=' AND '!=' operator overloading problem

Tags: c++

Okay, my evil compiler keeps rejecting my '=' AND '!=' overloaded operators for (I think) both my Polynomial and Rational classes. Help is greatly appreciated.

```
using namespace std;

class Polynomial
{

public:

//constructor
Polynomial() 
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < 100; i++ )
    {
        coefficient[i] = 0;
    }
    }

~Polynomial(){}

void polynomialSet ( Rational a , int b ) //polynomialSetter function
    {  
    coefficient[b] = a;
    exponent = b;
}

    . . . . 

    const Polynomial &Polynomial::operator=(const Polynomial &a)
{
    if (&a == this)
        return *this;
}

bool Polynomial::operator!=(Polynomial &a)
{       
    return !(*this == a);
    }

***************************************************************************
using namespace std;

class Rational {

public:
//constructors

Rational (int a, int b)
{
//Rational( const int &a, const int &b){
    if (a != 0)
    {
        if (b != 0)
        {
            this->numerator = a;
            this->denominator = b;
        }
    }
}

Rational(){}

~Rational() {}

    . . . .

    bool Rational::operator!=(Rational a)
{
    return (a.numerator != numerator) && (a.denominator != denominator);
}

Rational Rational::operator =(const Rational &a)
{
    this->numerator = a.numerator;
    this->denominator = a.denominator;
    return *this;
}
```

Here are my 3 error messages:

```
Polynomial.h(35) : error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a
right-hand operand of type 'int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
Rational.h(99): could be 'Rational Rational::operator =(const Rational &)'
while trying to match the argument list '(Rational, int)'

Polynomial.h(53) : error C2679: binary '!=' : no operator found which takes a  
right-hand operand of type 'int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
Rational.h(94): could be 'bool Rational::operator !=(Rational)'
while trying to match the argument list '(Rational, int)'

Polynomial.h(63) : error C2679: binary '!=' : no operator found which takes a
right-hand operand of type 'int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
Rational.h(94): could be 'bool Rational::operator !=(Rational)'
while trying to match the argument list '(Rational, int)'

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

HELP???

Comment: Btw, member functions that only inspect the object should be declared const, e.g. `bool Rational::operator!=(Rational a) const`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try reading the error messages?

```
binary '=' .... right-hand operand of type 'int' .... while trying to match the argument list '(Rational, int)'
```

Both operator = implementations that I can see take a `Rational&` or a `Polynomial&` but none take an int. That being said there is clearly some information missing from your question.

```
binary '!=' .... right-hand operand of type 'int' .... hile trying to match the argument list '(Rational, int)'
```

Same problem.

All that aside, `operator =` is an assignment operator... `operator ==` is Boolean equality. From what I can see of your code it looks like you have the two mixed up. Fixing that alone would set you well on your way to a solution.

Comment: Okay, I did that (I feel kinda stupid now).  I do get a few more error messages but I think I can figure them out.  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3):

The error messages actually just mean as they are. For instance:

```
Polynomial.h(35) : error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a
right-hand operand of type 'int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
Rational.h(99): could be 'Rational Rational::operator =(const Rational &)'
while trying to match the argument list '(Rational, int)'
```

Because you define your overloading as

```
Rational Rational::operator =(const Rational &a)
```

So it only accepts things like:

```
Rational r1 = new Rational(3, 5);
Rational r2 = r1; // calls r2.operator=(r1);
```

but not:

```
r2 = 3; // wrong, as the right hand operand is int, not Rational
```

Answer (score 0):

While I insist that you should indeed start accepting answers, here's my answer anyway:

I think you should override this method too:

Rational Rational::operator =(int a)

Because you're assigning your Rational object with an integer somewhere in your program.