# Union of two sets of structs in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have sets of SplinePoints and InterpolatedPoints. Their Union has to be stored in FinalInterpolatedPoints.

This is the main file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

typedef struct SplinePoints {
int x;
double y;
SplinePoints(int a, double b) : x(a), y(b) {

}
friend bool operator < (SplinePoints const&A, SplinePoints const&B) {
    return A.x < B.x;
}
};

typedef struct InterpolatedPoints {
int x;
double y;
InterpolatedPoints(int a, double b) : x(a), y(b) {

}
friend bool operator < (InterpolatedPoints const&A, 
                InterpolatedPoints const&B) {
    return A.x < B.x;
}
};

typedef struct FinalInterpolatedPoints {
int x;
double y;
FinalInterpolatedPoints(int a, double b) : x(a), y(b) {

}
friend bool operator < (FinalInterpolatedPoints const&A, 
                FinalInterpolatedPoints const&B) {
    return A.x < B.x;
}
FinalInterpolatedPoints operator= (SplinePoints const&A) {
    x = A.x;
    y = A.y;
    return *this;
}
FinalInterpolatedPoints operator= (InterpolatedPoints const&A) {
    x = A.x;
    y = A.y;
    return *this;
}
};

inline bool operator < (InterpolatedPoints const&A, 
                SplinePoints const&B) {
return A.x < B.x;
}

int main (int argc, char** argv) {

set <SplinePoints> set1;
set <InterpolatedPoints> set2;
set <FinalInterpolatedPoints> BaseLine;

set1.insert(SplinePoints(1,2));
set1.insert(SplinePoints(2,5));
set1.insert(SplinePoints(3,8));
set1.insert(SplinePoints(4,1.66));

set2.insert(InterpolatedPoints(5,5.768));
set2.insert(InterpolatedPoints(6,5.560));
set2.insert(InterpolatedPoints(7,5.643));
set2.insert(InterpolatedPoints(8,5.313));

set_union(set1.begin(), set1.end(), set2.begin(), set2.end(), inserter(BaseLine, BaseLine.begin()));

getch();
return 0;
}
```

I used this function to do that:

```
set_union(set1.begin(), set1.end(), set2.begin(), set2.end(), inserter(BaseLine, BaseLine.begin()));
```

where set1, set2 and BaseLine are of type SplinePoints, InterpolatedPoints and FinalInterpolatedPoints respectively.

When I debug the program I get template overloading error for `<` and '=' operators that are referenced to source file of header file `alogrithm`

```
template<class _InIt1,
class _InIt2,
class _OutIt> inline
_OutIt _Set_union(_InIt1 _First1, _InIt1 _Last1, _InIt2 _First2, _InIt2 _Last2, _OutIt _Dest)
{   // OR sets [_First1, _Last1) and [_First2, _Last2), using operator<
for (; _First1 != _Last1 && _First2 != _Last2; )
    **if (_DEBUG_LT(*_First1, *_First2))**
        {   // copy first
        ***_Dest++ = *_First1;**
        ++_First1;
        }
    **else if (*_First2 < *_First1)**
        {   // copy second
        ***_Dest++ = *_First2;**
        ++_First2;
        }
    else
        {   // advance both
        ***_Dest++ = *_First1;**
        ++_First1;
        ++_First2;
        }
_Dest = _STD copy(_First1, _Last1, _Dest);
return (_STD copy(_First2, _Last2, _Dest));
}
```

I included operator overloading function in the structure definitions but I was able to get rid of only errors related to `<` function. 
I am still having difficulties in removing error related to `=` i.e.:

`error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const SplinePoints' (or there is no acceptable conversion)`

Please help!

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331962/and-operator-overloading-problem

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
FinalInterpolatedPoints operator= (const SplinePoints &A)
```

That is, move the `const` keyword before the type (`SplinePoints`).

Answer (score 0):

Some things are odd with your code. Drop the `typedef` in front of the classes:

```
/*drop: typedef*/ struct SplinePoints {
```

and also, your `operator=`s should return a reference, e.g.,

```
FinalInterpolatedPoints& operator= (SplinePoints const&A) {
//                     ^ add this!
    x = A.x;
    y = A.y;
    return *this;
}
```

other than that, you haven't provided a compilable and complete example. If you still have problems after fixing the above, create one and edit the question, please.

Comment: That won't compile. SpliPoints must be declared as a struct everywhere it is used, when you don't typedef it. And there is a const in the wrong place in the function definition.

Comment: @fredrik: That might be case in C (even then it looks strange to me), but certainly not in C++. And the question is clearly labeled as C++.

Comment: @DanielFrey I removed the typedef and changes the code the way you said but still I am getting the same error.

Comment: Somehow I think you also have the types derived from each other - or you have different operators defined. Whatever it is, it makes no sense. Please post a COMPLETE, COMPILABLE example, otherwise we can not help you. (By compilable, I mean a small example which shows only the error you have problem with, but not any other error. Fix as much as you can yourself, ask about the one thing you are stuck with)

Comment: @DanielFrey I have posted the compilable code that you had asked for. During debuggind it gets only the error that I have mentioned.

Comment: @AnimeshPandey: I get lots of warnings for the `typedef`, errors for `operator<` (you said you fixed them, only `operator=` remains a problem) and I think you have a really strange compiler. Please add the compiler and version information to the question and hope for someone else (not me) who is knowledgable with that. Sorry.

Comment: @DanielFrey I am using Visual Studio 2010. Remove the typedefs and warnings will go away. I am getting only three errors that are for `operator=`!

Comment: @AnimeshPandey: I'm not using Windows at all and GCC or Clang (the compilers I'm using) are quite unhappy about your code as it is not standard conforming C++11. Sorry, I can't help you.